# How do you get the ethernet address using Java?

Tags: java, networking, ethernet

I would like to retrieve the ethernet address of the network interface that is used to access a particular website.

How can this be done in Java?

**Solution** Note that the accepted solution of `getHardwareAddress` is only available in Java 6. There does not seem to be a solution for Java 5 aside from executing i(f|p)confing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[java.net.NetworkInterface.getHardwareAddress](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getHardwareAddress%28%29) (method added in Java 6)

It has to be called on the machine you are interested in - the MAC is not transferred across network boundaries (i.e. LAN and WAN). If you want to make use of it on a website server to interrogate the clients, you'd have to run an applet that would report the result back to you.

For Java 5 and older I found code [parsing output of command line tools on various systems](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?messageID=3424868#4204392).

Comment: I think that more correct than *"across network boundaries"* is *"across network segments"*

Answer (score 4):

You can get the address that connects to your ServerSocket using http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getInetAddresses()

However if your client is connecting via a NAT, then you will get the address of the router and NOT the Ethernet address. If it is on your local network (via a hub/switch, no router with NAT) the it wil work as intended.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, beyond other right answers (JDK 6; exec 'ifconfig'), there are JNI-based libraries. [Java Uuid Generator (JUG) 2.0](http://jug.safehaus.org) has code for some platforms. This works on JDK 1.2 and above at least (maybe 1.1 even)